# iOS Enterprise Provisioning Profile Invalid - App doesn't launch

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, enterprise

My Enterprise app's provisioning profile became invalid yesterday. I renewed it via Xcode, but now the app on won't launch on any devices, and it's unable to download. Do I need to re-package the app and make all users download the update? The app has 3000+ users and making them all download it again would be a huge pain. Is there any way to update the profile, but not need to re-download the app? Shouldn't the device check against Apple's server and see the profile is now valid again?

Comment: Yes you will need to resign and re-distribute.  Do you have an MDM solution set up?  There might be a way to re-push the application payload to devices to avoid manually resigning and re-distributing, based on the MDM solution you are using and the feature set they support.

Comment: No, I'm not using an MDM unfortunately. Looks like I'll just have to re-distribute it. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have 3000 users, you really need to look into using an MDM / MAM platform to automate this.  Every year when the provisioning profile expires, you will need to re-sign the app, and then re-distribute the app to all the users.

You can do something in-app, like check for a new version, and prompt the user on launch that they must download the new version.  If you do this, make sure you push it out early enough that all users will launch the app and download the new version before the profile expiration date.  So every year, 1 month before the profile expires, you push a new version to a particular location.  Users will then get a pop up saying they must get the new version.  They click OK and it fires off the install from the .plist, replacing the current version. We do it for a much smaller user base and it has been effective.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly how we push out updates at the moment. It checks on launch for a new version. We should have been more on top of it, we didn't realise the expiry was coming up.